# Xen not running hvms (but CPU supports vmx)

Tags: virtualization, centos, xen

I am trying to create an HVM DomU on a Centos5 system. When I run the command

```
virt-install -n build1a -r 2048 --vcpus=4 --os-type=linux --hvm --disk path=/dev/guests/build1a --network=bridge:eth0 --vnc --vncport=1 --location http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.6/os/x86_64/
```

It immediately fails with

```
ERROR    Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'
```

I am running a Core-i5 and here is the output of `egrep '^flags.*(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`

```
flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc ida arat pni vmx est ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc ida arat pni vmx est ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc ida arat pni vmx est ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc ida arat pni vmx est ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have virtualization enabled in the bios.